# Apache returning 404 for requests inside /javascript directory

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I have a project with several sub-directories. Everything works just fine, except if I try to access files inside the /root/javascript directory, I get a 404. The files do in fact exist, and I am in fact typing the path correctly. If I simply rename the directory I can then access the files. Rename it back, and I get the 404 again. VHost file works fine. No .htaccess files involved.

Apache version: 2.4.9

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: rename the directory to what?

Comment: Anything. I've added an answer that explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 8):

After much searching and trying different things, here's what the problem came down to:

By default, Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu enables a config file called javascript-common, which redirects any requests to files inside /javascript (that is, a directory at the root of your project called 'javascript') to /usr/share/javascript.

**Solution 1**

Use the following command to disable the javascript-common configuration file:

```
a2disconfig javascript-common
```

**Solution 2**

Add your JavaScript files inside that /usr/share/javascript directory. That way Apache will actually find those files and no 404 will be returned. One benefit of doing things this way is that you won't need multiple copies of the same files (jquery.js, etc.js) that multiple projects use...

**Solution 3**

Delete the directory /usr/share/javascript, and create a symbolic link that points to your project's /javascript directory. Keep in mind that if you have more than one project (vhost file), they will all serve from the same JavaScript file from the original project. In other words, this is probably not the best solution...

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 it's called `a2disconf` for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The a2disconfig solution didn't work for me, but then through some searching, I realized that the javascript-common is something that can be uninstalled.

So I fixed the problem by removing javascript-common:

```
sudo apt-get remove javascript-common
```

I'm not sure the point of this package, or why it would be installed automatically, but I'm glad that my javascript files are loading again!

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with the lamp-server bundle

Encountering the same problem, I found a similar answer resolved it.

sudo a2disconf javascript-common
sudo service apache2 restart

After the a2disconf (and note it is apparently now a2disconf and not a2disconfig) 
I did get a message to execute "sudo service apache2 reload"

the reload did not resolve the issue... thus the restart

as an aside -- I cannot imagine what the developers were thinking when they loaded this little gem -- some of my javascript files might be viable across domains... but certainly not all !

Answer (score 0):

You could just override /javascript alias in your .conf to reflect what you want:

Alias /javascript /my_custom_dir